# WebBrowser control does not work with some javascript constructs

Tags: javascript, wpf, winforms, hyperlink, webbrowser-control

i have found that WebBrowser control (both Winforms and WPF) has certain javascript constructs not supported especially when they are rendered using showModalDialog / showModelessDialog calls....

This is easily reproducible...

1) Create a test html page such as `C:\Temp\Test.htm` with this code..

```
    <input type=button
           onclick="showModalDialog('C:\\Temp\\Test.htm');"
           value="Show Me as Modal Page." />
    <BR />
    <a href="javascript:alert('I am shown.')">
       I should work using href.
    </a>
    <BR />
    <a href="#"
       onclick="javascript:alert('I am shown.')">
       I should work using onclick.
    </a>
```

If you load the page above using the IE browser, both hyperlinks should work. Now in the IE browser, if you you click the "Show Me as Modal Page." button, the same page opens as MSHTML dialog window and again on that both hyperlinks work.

This is expected.

2) Now create a `WPF` or `WinForm` app hosting `WebBrowser` control sourced to "C:\Temp\Test.htm"

```
    <WebBrowser Source="C:\Temp\Test.htm" Height="500" Width="500"/>
```

If you run the app and load the test page using the `WebBrowser` control, both hyperlinks will work on the loaded page.

**But** if you load the modal window using the "Show Me as Modal Page." button, then the modal window **fails** to alert using the first hyperlink i.e. **`I should work using href.`** does not appear.

Second hyperlink works as expected.

Do you guys reckon is there a workaround for the first hyperlink to work?

In my case I have no access to the page's content that I am loading using the `javascript:showModalDialog()` call, so the issue fix is intended from the web browser's perspective.

**EDIT**

They say that **`FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION`** has to be enabled for this. But it is already enabled in my registry. The MSDN continues to say ...

> By default, this feature is enabled for Internet Explorer and disabled
>   for applications hosting the **WebBrowser** Control. It has to be manually enabled for 
>   **webBrowser** control.

How to enable this for the web browser control?

Comment: hope this help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thx and tried the same. FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION registry setting is enabled on my machine. Hence as I said when the page is loaded directly onto web browser control it works. But the same page loaded using `showModalDialog()` dialog doesnt work for a-href javascript calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> This feature **is not supported** for applications hosting the **WebBrowser
>   Control**.

Comment: I knew that it doesnt work by default. My machine's works when `FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION` registry setting is enabled . Thats why the first page works when loaded on webbrowser control. But the same page loaded using `showModalDialog()` fails to call a-href javascripts.

Comment: According to that hyperlink it's impossible to use this feature in WebBrowser control ModalDialog.

Comment: Hmmm missed that. Bounty for you! :-)